# How to remove empty white space at the bottom of the screen in NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I'm using a NestedScrollView to make the carousel and viewPager scrollable. I added the carousel on the main layout because I need it on all pages from the tab layout. All the pages of the tab layout have only a recycler view in the fragment. The problem is that on the bottom of the screen there is a lot of empty white space that I can't figure out how to remove.

This is the main layout activity xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue_primary"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.SplashscreenActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTopBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_xlarge"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        ////// irrelevant code

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainTopBar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:background="@color/blue_primary"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/plan_popular_gradient_1"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/featured_height"
                    app:icvp_interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                    app:icvp_scroll_duration="3000"
                    app:icvp_center_page_scale_offset="@dimen/icon_size_large"
                    app:icvp_min_page_scale_offset="@dimen/margin_padding_size_xmedium"
                    app:icvp_max_page_scale="0.8"
                    app:icvp_min_page_scale="0.55"
                    app:icvp_medium_scaled="false"/>

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

This is the fragments xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_layout_content_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.AppLayoutFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/app_layout_scroll_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

This is the recycler view item xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_item_content_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemHomeTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemHomeRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

I tried all the answers I could find on stackoverflow (you can see all the attributes on the NestedScrollView) but none of them fixed my problem.

Comment: send your screenshot

Comment: The app is still in development so I can't show the content displayed on it

Comment: just show how's your white space is looking with code nobody can understand what you want to express .if there is logical issue then I understand but its a ui issue .

Comment: bro the problem might not be with the nested scroll view. I implemented your layouts in android studio and the only important thing that I didn't have was @dimen/featured_height (on HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager) which you have set as height.
I used something myself and everything looks fine and there is no empty space. double check that @dimen/featured_height

Comment: When I use a scroll view instead of a NestedScrollView the empty space disappears that's why I believed the problem was with the NestedScrollView .  I tried setting the height of the HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager to wrap_content and also to a smaller height from 200dp to 180dp but the empty space stays the same. What did you use for height?